# satellite map view not show in fragment

Tags: android

```
@EFragment(R.layout.main_map)
public class MapActivity extends Fragment {
      private GoogleMap map;
      static final LatLng DURG = new LatLng(21.1900,81.2800);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_map, container, false);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        return view;
    }

}
```

> Null pointer exception error occure at map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE).

R.layout.main_map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_id" 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your `R.layout.main_map`. You need to initialise your `map` variable, it is null.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_id"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: First call `map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_id)).getMap()`, then `map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add MapFragment Dynamically when you want to inflate a MapFragment inside a Fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_map, container, false);
    SupportMapFragmentmf = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, mf, "normal_map").commit();
    mf.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
            map = arg0;
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

where your main_map should be like below

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I hope that helps. Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: my mistake, i edited it.please try the edited one and let me know.

Comment: replace() in FragmentTransaction can not be applied to android.support.v4.app.Fragment mf (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment)

Comment: i have edited it again. I did not  know that you are using supportFragments. Try the updated answer.

Comment: this = {sjain.ventures.nanotaxi.fragment.MapActivity$1@830038993760}
this$0 = {sjain.ventures.nanotaxi.fragment.MapActivity_@830038916328}"MapActivity_{422cbce8 #0 id=0x7f0a006b HOME}"
contentView_ = {android.widget.RelativeLayout@830038985592}"android.widget.RelativeLayout{422dcb78 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-600,887}"
onViewChangedNotifier_ = {org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier@830038916560}
map = null
mActivity = {sjain.ventures.nanotaxi.MainActivity@830037052512}
mWho = {java.lang.String@830038928096}"android:fragment:0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78082/discussion-between-dora-and-roshan-bharti).

Comment: on   map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE); it crashes

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)
```

then in the callback you can set the map to satellite view